play temp file (created by combining raw flac files) in android app using mediaplayer

I have raw files named zero.flac , one.flac , ... , nine.flac
My app has minimum api 28 and I am using kotlin.
My app will take number input from user and read it sequentially
There will be option to read normal, fast , faster and fastest for which i will adjust playback speed of mediaplayer
Suppose number is 123 then i will join one.flac , two.flac and three.flac to make a temporary file which I want to pass to mediaplayer
I am taking example of playing just one file (zero.flac) here .
Later , i think i will need sequence input stream to handle multiple numbers as intended.
Here is my relevant code
      val ins = resources.openRawResource(
                resources.getIdentifier(
                "zero",
                "raw", packageName
        )
       )

        val outputFile = File(this.cacheDir, "output.flac")
        val outputStream = FileOutputStream(outputFile)
        ins.use { input ->
            outputStream.use { output ->
                input.copyTo(output)
            }
        }
        val mp = MediaPlayer()

As you can see that I made an input stream from zero.flac and made an output file.
Now how to pass it to mediaplayer for playing it ?
I tried
val myuri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,this.packageName+".provider",outputFile)
        mp.setDataSource(this,myuri)
        mp.prepare()
        mp.start()

i don't get error . but app stops on first run .
I hope that given information is relevant and sufficient.
If not , please give helpful suggestion.
Thanks.

I used following code
Here I make input stream , each input stream contains one raw resource content as per requirement then combine them using SequenceInputStream
lateinit var seq:SequenceInputStream
lateinit var numone:InputStream
lateinit var numtwo:InputStream
lateinit var prefixtonumber:InputStream
lateinit  var mediaPlayer: MediaPlayer

               prefixtonumber = resources.openRawResource(
                    resources.getIdentifier(
                        strfilenameforprefixtonumber ,
                        "raw", packageName
                    ))
        
                            numone = resources.openRawResource(
                                resources.getIdentifier(
                                    strfilenamefornumone,
                                    "raw", packageName
                                )
                            )
        seq = SequenceInputStream(prefixtonumber, SequenceInputStream(numone,numtwo) )
    val outputDir: File = this.getCacheDir() // context being the Activity pointer
            val outputFile = File.createTempFile("prefix", ".extension", outputDir)
            val outputStream = FileOutputStream(outputFile)
            seq.use { input ->
                outputStream.use { output ->
                    input.copyTo(output)
                }
            }
            if (this::mymp.isInitialized) {
            Log.d("mediaplayer","mediaplayer already here")
            mymp.reset() }
        else
        {
            mymp= MediaPlayer()
            Log.d("mediaplayer","making mediaplayer")
        }
            mymp.setDataSource(this, Uri.fromFile(outputFile))
            mymp.setOnCompletionListener {
    
                //some GUI stuff
            }
            mymp.playbackParams = PlaybackParams().setSpeed(playBackSpeed)
            mymp.prepare()
            mymp.start()

